# how to make inputs in angular accept only specific data

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, form-control, angular-validator

Im working on an angular project and i want to create an input that only accepts 3 values 0, 0.5, 1 and if the user enters for example 0.4 he will get an error message and tell him to enter only one of the 3 values{ 0 / 0.5 / 1 }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Angular [template-driven form](https://angular.io/guide/forms#build-a-template-driven-form) with [pattern validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/PatternValidator), like below:

***app.component.ts***

```
export class AppComponent {
  model: any = {};
}
```

***app.component.html***

```
<input
  type="number"
  name="quantity"
  [(ngModel)]="model.quantity"
  #quantity="ngModel"
  pattern="^(0|0.5|1)$"
  required
/>
<div *ngIf="quantity.invalid && (quantity?.dirty || quantity?.touched)">
  Quantity is invalid! Only allowed values are: 0, 0.5, 1
</div>
```

A Stackblitz to try on: [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1monau?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: i added ^(0|0.5|1)$ to Validators.pattern and it worked perfectly ty